# Storyboard does not render controls

Tags: ios, swift4, xcode9, xcode10

I dragged some controls onto `UIViewController` and `UITableViewController` and they do not render. Whenever I run pod update this happens. The behavior is not constant. Sometimes when I quit Xcode and open it again, sometimes the controls appear. Since some days the behavior has been very bad, for some scenes, Xcode does not render controls.
[image]

Comment: are these controls built into iOS (and UIKit), or are these controls that come from your Cocoapods?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann: They are from both pod and UIKit. Those two highlighted wider UIViews at the bottom in the highlighted rectangle. They are IBDesignable

Comment: Could you try Xcode 10?

Comment: It is same on Xcode 10.1 (10B61) too!

Comment: It happens due to pod class. I don't know the solution yet but have a workaround which is, if you remove pod class from identity inspector of all view in view controller then all controls get appear. Then you can add constraints or whatever you have to do and then again set pod class in identity inspector. This is just a workaround.

Comment: @HiteshAgarwal: This worked. Please provide it as answer, will accept. Edit: Again, if I open storyboard, the rendering is again transparent.

Answer (score 0):

It happens due to pod class. I don't know the solution yet but have a workaround which is, if you remove pod class from identity inspector of all view in view controller then all controls get appear. Then you can add constraints or whatever you have to do and then again set pod class in identity inspector. This is just a workaround.

I don't know the reason behind these issues.